# Unfold summarised dataframe in r

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

```
df <- data.frame(
  date = rep("2020-01-01", times = 10),
  letter = LETTERS[1:10],
  values = c(10, 1, 2, 5, 2, 1, 7, 4, 5, 8)
)
```

I would like to get the data frame unfolded
haveng one row for every letter and every value of 1 if it is > 1.

`date letter value
2020-01-01 A 1
-,-,-
2020-01-01 J 1`

Comment: Unclear. Could you elaborate please? Do you want to have multiple data.frame?

Comment: No, I want to unsum the dataframe, and repeat the rows (if value >1) getting for exampt 10 letters of A, 1 B, 2 C ect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do that with `uncount`:

```
tidyr::uncount(df, values)
```

Or if you want to keep the `values` column:

```
tidyr::uncount(df, values, .remove = FALSE)
```

Comment: Great shortcut but code will be slower as it just used `rep` inside, check `tidyr::uncount` in console

Comment: Thanks! As for the benchmark, I've quickly checked on 100k rows and they look pretty similar. Yes `base` is faster but likely you wouldn't notice it.

Comment: Totally agree, just to precise that `uncount` is only a wrapper of `base`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rep` in base R:

```
expand <- df[rep(1:nrow(df), df$values),]
expand$values <- 1
head(expand)
          date letter values
1   2020-01-01      A      1
1.1 2020-01-01      A      1
1.2 2020-01-01      A      1
1.3 2020-01-01      A      1
1.4 2020-01-01      A      1
1.5 2020-01-01      A      1
```

Comment: thanks, any dplyr way to do it? I want to repet it 10 times if value is 10.

Comment: `df[rep(1:nrow(df), df$values),] %>% mutate(values = 1)`

Comment: @RafikMargaryan base R code will be faster that `dplyr` or `tidyr` solutions